# JSON Data Not showing from to view after retrieving using ajax

Tags: javascript, c#, json, asp.net-ajax

I retrieve Json data from controller using ajax. But I am trying to show the result in a specific div and tried so many things but couldn't figure it out what I am doing wrong. I can see in console that it is getting the json Data but it is just not showing in the specific div.

Here is the Json Data -

```
Object
postage_result:
  costs:
       cost:{item: "Parcel Post", cost: "15.80"}
  delivery_time:"Delivered in 4 business days"
  service:"Parcel Post"
  total_cost:"15.80"
```

Ajax Code-

```
<script>
        $.ajax({
            url: '/ShoppingCart/GetFreight',
            type: 'GET',
            success: function (response) {
                console.log(response);

                weather = ko.mapping.fromJS(response);  //populate the weather object
                ko.applyBindings(weather);
                $.each(response.postage_result, function (i, val) {
                    $("#cost").append(document.createTextNode(val.total_cost));
                })

            },
            error: function (error) {
                $(that).remove();
                DisplayError(error.statusText);
            }
        });
    </script>
```

View Code -

```
<td>Freight =<div id="cost"> </div></td>
```

Please suggest How should I do it to work .